# ways(ldapsearch, getenv passwd,java API) could not search uidNumber but it has been set in Microsoft AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pam

I tried much and almost see the hope of logging onto Linux(CENT OS 6) against MS Active Directory with pure LDAP(pam_ldap) using [nslcd](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Nslcd). The problem is as the title. The information is as below.

1. I run nslcd with debug mode: `nslcd -d`. Then I log on with user ricky but failed. the error from nslcd is

> ```
> nslcd: [334873] DEBUG:
> ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***")
> (uri="ldap://192.168.0.82:3268")
> nslcd: [334873] ***passwd entry CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com 
> does not contain uidNumber value***
> nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of result
> ```

I got the same error/message/result when I use command **getent passwd 8888/ldapsearch or java API(Apache Directory Studio)** that is the **uidNumber** cannot be seen/searched. Below is the output of ldapsearch in the target Linux server. you can see the result does not have the uidNUmber and gidNumber returned. the user is a posixAccount

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.0.82:3268 -D "CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com" -b "CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com" -W sAMAccountName=ricky
```

> ```
> dn: CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> objectClass: top
> **objectClass: posixAccount**
> objectClass: person
> objectClass: organizationalPerson
> objectClass: user
> cn: ricky
> sn: ricky
> distinguishedName: CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> instanceType: 4
> whenCreated: 20180817065146.0Z
> whenChanged: 20180818120211.0Z
> displayName: ricky
> uSNCreated: 12923
> memberOf: CN=unixgrp,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> memberOf: CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> uSNChanged: 20561
> name: ricky
> objectGUID:: 4LUI5gIJoUGi3E/FAOzCwg==
> userAccountControl: 66048
> primaryGroupID: 513
> objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAkBu6Z6KeddWjPO/ceAQAAA==
> sAMAccountName: ricky
> sAMAccountType: 805306368
> userPrincipalName: ricky@kelamayi.com
> objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> dSCorePropagationData: 20180817082734.0Z
> dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
> lastLogonTimestamp: 131789626301116683
> ```

2. I set the uidNumber and gidNumber in AD in Windows Server 2012 R2 and can search it through windows command.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADUser –Identity ricky -Properties uidNumber, gidNumber
```

> ```
> DistinguishedName : CN=ricky,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
> Enabled           : True
> gidNumber         : 9999
> GivenName         :
> Name              : ricky
> ObjectClass       : user
> ObjectGUID        : e608b5e0-0902-41a1-a2dc-4fc500ecc2c2
> SamAccountName    : ricky
> SID               : S-1-5-21-1740250000-3581255330-3706666147-1144
> Surname           : ricky
> uidNumber         : 8888
> UserPrincipalName : ricky@kelamayi.com
> ```

This makes me think it may be a problem in AD side...But still looking for the reason.

Comment: Is uidNumber in the Global Catalog?

Comment: @jwilleke, thank you for your help. After I did "Replicate this attribute to the Global Catalog" for uidNumber,gidNumber,unixHomeDirectory and refresh AD server. I made it.